# D3 How to create a graph

Tags: d3.js

I created with NodeXL this graph

[Graph](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/37124455/GraphImage.png)

Just in case the link will stop work in the future, the graph is a directed, grouped in clusters in different boxes.

I want to create a similar (or the same graph) and upload it in a website with D3. I haven't used before the D3 and it will be the first time, so if you want to suggest anything else, you are welcome.

I tried to find an example that will fit with my graph in the official gallery, but without a success.

Do you know any example or a tutorial that will fit to this graph?

P.S. The specific graph is a frequent one, that's why I ask a question here.

Comment: Something like [this](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1747543)?

Comment: Hello @LarsKotthoff, If I could include edges too, it would be nice. I saw it in the gallery when I searched for something similar, but I thought that it won't help me.

Comment: There's nothing stopping you including links.

Comment: Well. I will try it tonight and if I can handle it, I will update the first post with the code or a jsfiddle. Thank you :)